# Neo4j Cypher return multiple counts from a single query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

For analytical purpose, I need to return multiple counts from a single query.

For example, I have a `User` entity. User has `active` property `true`/`false`.

Is it possible with Cypher to write a single query which will return a total number of all users, and also 2 additional count for active and inactive users? If so, please show how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the counts of active and inactive users. It is similar to SQL wherein it uses the sum() function and conditional clause "case when".

```
MATCH (n:Person) 
RETURN count(n) as user_counts, 
      sum(case when n.active then 1 end) as active, 
      sum(case when not n.active then 1 end) as inactive,
      sum(case when n.active is NULL then 1 end) as no_info
```

Sample result using Persons nodes in movie database

```
╒═════════════╤════════╤══════════╤═════════╕
│"user_counts"│"active"│"inactive"│"no_info"│
╞═════════════╪════════╪══════════╪═════════╡
│133          │121     │7         │5        │
└─────────────┴────────┴──────────┴─────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

We can simply use:

```
Match(p:Persons)`
RETURN count(p) as total_user,
  sum(case when not p.active then 1 end) as inactive_users,
  sum(case when p.active then 1 end) as active_users,
  sum(case when p.active is NULL then 1 end) as remaining_users
```